# How can I do to run faster my InfoWindows?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

Hi guys I have a map in a Fragment of my app and I wanna print on the Infowindows travel times, but it takes some seconds to appear because the app do a HTTP request to Google Maps and receive the times, so how can I do to open faster infowindows in you opinion? Thank you.

[image: myapp]

and this is my code:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                        /* Distanza a piedi e macchina sulla nuvoletta */
                        /***********************************************/
                        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation() && is_online == true)
                        {
                            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
                            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
                            String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(MainActivity.this);
                            String city = gpsTracker.getLocality(MainActivity.this);
                            String postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(MainActivity.this);

                            double currentLat = Double.parseDouble(stringLatitude);
                            double currentLng = Double.parseDouble(stringLongitude);

                            double destLat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                            double destLng = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                            final float[] results = new float[3];
                            Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLng, destLat, destLng, results);

                            float metri = results[0];
                            float km = Math.round((double)metri/1000);

                            int minuti_persona = (int)Math.round(metri/125);    //125 metri al minuto -> velocità media di 2,5 m/s
                            int minuti_auto = (int)Math.round(km/0.7);          //700 metri al minuto -> velocità media di 42 km/h 


                        /***********************************************/


                            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
                            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                            TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                            tvSnippet.setTypeface(tvSnippet.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC); //indirizzo in corsivo
                            TextView tvPedonal_distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pedonal_time);
                            TextView tvCar_distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.car_time);
                            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                            if(minuti_persona <=0)          // Stampa tempo per coprire la distanza
                            {
                                tvCar_distance.setText("A piedi: meno di un minuto");
                            }else
                            {
                                tvPedonal_distance.setText("A piedi: "+minuti_persona+ " minuti");
                            }

                            if(minuti_auto <= 0)
                            {
                                tvCar_distance.setText("In auto: meno di un minuto");                                   
                            }else
                            {
                                tvCar_distance.setText("In auto: " +minuti_auto+ " minuti");
                            }

                            return v;
                        }else
                        {
                            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
                            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                            TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                            return v;
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems that times are calculated solely based by geographical locations, without any external help. Network requests are probably involved by asking country, city and postalcode for current location. (cant be 100% sure because its not clear what is in GPSTracker class) As you are currently not using these variables you should remove them and your infowindow will appear faster.

Comment: Now I try. I declared that because I thought, maybe I will need them.